# Java Swing JSpinner with NumberEditor to display blank rather than zero

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a JSpinner with a Number Editor along the lines of:

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50000,1));
spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner,"# ###"));
```

The default value is zero but I want it to be displayed as blank. The problem I am trying to solve is that a user may tab to the spinner and type in 100 but because of the initial 0(zero) it becomes 1000. If it is not possible to have zero show as blank in a numeric spinner, is there any way to automatically have any value in the spinner selected on focus so that in my previous scenario the user would automatically overwrite the default zero? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get textfield from your editor. `public JFormattedTextField getTextField()` 
Then onFocusGained call `public void selectAll()`

Comment: and `selectAll()` wrapped into `invokeLater()` +1

Comment: Thanks. That works. Ideally though I would like to display the spinner blank if that is possible but if I do not get any suggestions on how to do that i will accept this as the answer later today.